# Uninstall Apache using make

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, apache-http-server, uninstall, httpd

I installed httpd using `make`. But i cant find any remove/uninstall method in README or INSTALL files. Also, i searched the http://apache.org docs. There also there is no mention of uninstalling using make.

Actually, i didnt pass the PREFIX value, and it got installed into /usr/local/apache/.
Is it fine? Where would it be installed by `sudo apt-get install apache2`?

Thanks,
Jeff

p.s.I am using Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 2):

There is no uninstall provided by most make installed packages.

On Ubuntu, the apache2 .deb package is installed:

```
$ which apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming there is no `make uninstall` for apache then.

Your only option is to identify what files are created and edited by the make install process and manually remove them or edit them again.
Do you need to uninstall apache?

It doesn't help for this occasion, but you could have used ***checkinstall*** which tracks builds made using `make install` and creates a deb file so you easily remove it afterwards if required.